# Using auto generated model file object outside of CoreData

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I have a CoreData entity called `MessageDetailStore` that saves incoming messages.  Since messages can be received at different places, I have a common method called `-insertMessage:txt:` which is called to handle the insertion of a message into a queue (it also does other things like check for duplicates, update related tables, etc.).  Initially I had the argument of the function be of type `NSDictionary` with each key/value corresponding one entry in the `MessageDetailStore` entity.  This works.

I decided that I will get some type-safety and other protection by making the input argument of the method of type = auto-generated class corresponding to `MessageDetailStore`.  Code is below.

Looks like this won't work because `[[alloc] init]` does not generate the object, I need to use `-initWithEntity:insertIntoManagedObjectContext:`.  But using the latter will result in a new entity being added to the object graph.  But I want this to be done only after doing all sorts of checks.  Is there any way to create an instance of the "auto-genereated" class outside of CoreData?

```
     MessageDetailTable *messageToStoreFromPush =[[MessageDetailTable alloc] init] ;
     messageToStoreFromPush.isMedia=FALSE ;
     messageToStoreFromPush.msgContent=dict[@"msg"]  
     messageToStoreFromPush.sendingUserID=dict[@"sendingUser"] ;
     messageToStoreFromPush.seqNumber=[NSNumber numberWithInt:[dict[@"seqNum"] intValue]] ;

     [self insertBcastMessage:messageToStoreFromPush] ;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `init` because it's not the designated initializer for `NSManagedObject`. But the thing about `initWithEntity:insertIntoManagedObjectContext:` is that the second argument is allowed to be nil. If you do that, you get a new instance that's not yet inserted into the context. Later, if your checks pass, you can use `insertObject:` to insert it before saving changes.

Comment: Thanks.  Looks like this is exactly what I was looking for.  Unfortunately, due to deadline I just went ahead and implemented the plain old NSDictionary approach.  When I get some time, I will create branch and test out option above and let you know if it works.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at `-[NSManagedObjectContext insertObject:]`.